# Docker base image for perl; E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate

Tags: perl, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, libssl

I have a dockerfile that uses perl:5.22 as the base image
When I do:

```
#Dockerfile:

From perl:5.22
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
```

I get this error:
When I do: `sudo apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0` in the dockerfile, like this:

```
#Dockerfile:

From perl:5.22
RUN apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0 && \
    apt-cache policy libssl-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

I get:

> Step 2/3 : RUN apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0 &&     apt-cache policy
>   libssl-dev  ---> Running in a60f0185ef5a libssl1.0.0:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: (none)
>   Version table: 
>   libssl-dev:
>   Installed: 1.1.0f-3+deb9u2
>   Candidate: 1.1.0f-3+deb9u2
>   Version table:
>   *** 1.1.0f-3+deb9u2 500
>           500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
>           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>        1.1.0f-3+deb9u1 500
>           500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages

There's no available candidate to install ***`libssl1.0.0`***; I get:

> E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate

However there's a candidate to install the ***`libssl-dev`*** package, but none for the ***`libssl1.0.0`***

I'm new with docker; ***does [the perl 5.22 base image](https://github.com/perl/docker-perl/blob/1c201e950ebe90f35c449f69df6ca7151cb0068d/5.022.004-64bit/Dockerfile) already come with libssl1.0.0 already preinstalled in the image?*** I couldn't see it in their base image and secondly, ***how do I install this package** `(libssl1.0.0)` **in my dockerfile if there's no candidate available to install it***?

Lastly, since the base image already comes preinstalled with the libssl-dev could I use this package, ***`libssl-dev`***, instead of the libssl1.0.0, ***is there a difference between `libssl-dev` and `libssl1.0.0`*** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is already installed by default.

```
$ docker run -it perl:5.22 /bin/bash
root@e5315bc25223:~# apt search libssl
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libssl-dev/now 1.1.0f-3+deb9u2 amd64 [installed,local]
  Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files

libssl1.0.0/now 1.0.1t-1+deb8u8 amd64 [installed,local]
  Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
```

---

<s>The perl image is based on debian:stretch, which no longer supports libssl1.0.0. You can pull the package from jessie (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libssl1.0.0) and install with `dpkg`.</s>

Sample Dockerfile addition:

```
RUN wget "http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u8_amd64.deb" \
    && dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u8_amd64.deb
```

Regarding the version, `apt show libssl-dev` gives:

> Package: libssl-dev
>
> Version: 1.1.0f-3+deb9u2

As far as if you can use 1.1.0 instead of 1.0.0, that really depends on your software's requirements.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, could I use this package, ***`libssl-dev`***, instead of the ***`libssl1.0.0`***? I was NOT alluding 1.1.0 vs 1.0.0 - the base perl image comes preinstalled with libssl-dev so ... can I use libssl-dev instead of the libssl1.0.0 ? or there's a difference between those two packages?

Comment: `libssl-dev` contains version 1.1.0. If you need specifically 1.0.0, you have to install 1.0.0 directly.

Comment: Thanks, when you ran that apt show ... you were trying to show that libssl-dev and libssl1.0.0 are the same utility package but just different versions right? I'm not familiar with those 2 packages; putting the versions aside, I want to know if one could use the libdev or the libssl interchangeably; are they the same package but one is optimized for prod and the other for development i.e the dash dev part (libssl-dev) ?

Comment: Right. Though strictly speaking `libssl-dev` contains headers and development libraries, whereas `libssl1.0.0` contains shared libraries. Their uses are a bit different.

Comment: Makes sense! And it worked for me now with the above solution, thanks